# Setting background color in li element causes text to become transparent. (IE8)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a document with the following markup:

```
<li style="background-color: #{background_color}; color: black;">
  <a href="#{url}" title="#{action_name}" style="color: black;"
    <span style='color: black;'>action_name</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

However, whenever I set the background_color to anything at all, it causes the link text to become transparent. What can be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified a link color--only the text color... which is *not* the same. For links, you want to specific their properties explicitly... and preferably, not with in-line styles; for example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a.mainLink:link { color : black; } //this order is important
    a.mainLink:visited { color : black; } // "L" o "V" e, "H" "A" t e
    a.mainLink:hover { color : white; } // is an easy way to remember.
    a.mainLink:active { color : black; }

    li.mainList { background : #555; }
</style>
```

and then for your link and list:

```
<li class="mainList">    
<a href="{url}" title="action_name" class="mainLink">'action_name'</a>
</li>
```

In-line styles are nice for dynamically generated content, but it's better (and more predictable) to define styles in an external stylesheet, or within the `<head>` tag.